# Writing and then displaying the number of even numbers written to a file (Beginner C++ Visual Studio)

Tags: c++

In this program I need to write 3 integers to a text file and then display the number of even integers entered into the file. My code runs with no errors, the numbers get written to the file, but the cout statements within my if statements do not display for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    ofstream outFile;
    cout << "Enter three integers:\n";
    cout << "#1:    ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "#2:    ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "#3:    ";
    cin >> num3;
    outFile << num1 << endl << num2 << endl << num3 << endl;
    outFile.close();
    if (num1 % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "One even number was written to the file.";
    }
    else if (num2 % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Two even numbers were written to the file.";
    }
    else if (num3 % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Three even numbers were written to the file.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No even numbers were written to the file.";
    }
    outFile.open("Text.txt", ios::app);
    if (!outFile)
        {
            cout << "File did not open.";
            return 1;
        }
    outFile << num1 << endl << num2 << endl << num3 << endl;
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
    system("pause");


}
```

Comment: Time to step through your code with a debugger and find out why.

Comment: I think the debugger is F5 but how does it help me? I am not getting any errors when I run it

Comment: @SpencerCumbie that's why you need a debugger!  Step through, line by line, and watch the flow of control and inspect the variable values to see why decisions are taken, or not.

Comment: 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.                                                                                                     
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.      This is 2 lines from my debugger, I still dont know what this has to do with my code

Comment: Do you need to write to the output file twice?

Comment: BTW, when a function encounters a `return` statement, it returns at that point.  Statements following a `return` will not be executed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use different logic:

```
int count = 0;
if (num1 % 2 == 0)
{
  ++count;
}
if (num2 % 2 == 0)
{
  ++count;
}
if (num3 % 2 == 0)
{
  ++count;
}
std::cout << "There were " << count << " even numbers written to the file.\n";
```

The above code counts the number of even numbers, then outputs the value.  No need for `else` clauses.

Comment: I appreciate you so much, this was my issue. I knew I needed to re-write the if statements because my original code didn't account for all the possibilities, I just didn't know how to go about it. Thank you for not down voting this post and telling me I need a tutor but instead actually helping me. This site needs more users like you.